# Let X1, X2, …, Xn be an iid sample of Bernoulli random variables, Find the likelihood function, MLE,sufficiency

Tags: statistics

[image]

(a)Find the likelihood function, $L(\theta)$

$$L(\theta)=(x_1,x_2,x_3.....x_n|\theta)= \theta^{x(1-\theta)^{(1-x)}} ?$$

(b) find the MLE

MLE is $\theta =x$

not sure how to show the sufficiency and how to show the MlE as a unbiased estimator

Comment: Have you calculated the MLE and you need only the sufficiency and the unbiasedness, or do you need everything?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the MLE solution, maximize the log-likelihood of the sample pdf:

$$max_\theta \sum_i~\log f(x_i;\theta)$$

For the sufficiency test form the likelihood ratio and move on from there.

You may like to take a look at Neyman-Pearson and Lehman-Scheffe theorems.